# How did Anakin manage to cut off the hands of Dooku, supposedly a superior swordsman?

Tags: star-wars

I just re-watched *Revenge Of The Sith* again, and I just noticed something.

It seems when  Anakin cut off Dooku's hands he just beat him by sheer luck, not technique. He just held the saber under Dooku's saber and just sweeped off his hands.

Am I correct about this or was it more than that? Maybe perhaps Dooku intentionally lost?

Comment: You're expecting technique from one of Lucas's choreographed battles? Let's face it, people don't swing blades at other blades in combat.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart - In cases like this, a simple edit is appropriate.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart - sorry, my bad. I mis-typed during my edit, if you check the edit history it was correct in the original version.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - Lucas (much as I love to dump on him) didn't choreograph the swordfighting in the movies. An expert swordfighter and experienced stuntman did.

Comment: On which basis, are you saying Dooku superior swordman?

Comment: @SachinShekhar - it's a well known fact from canon. He defeated Anakin and OB1 before too.

Comment: @DVK That was long ago. Anakin himself said about his improvements to Dooku.

Comment: @SachinShekhar - that's besides the point. Anakin's improvement didn't mean DOoku was NOT a superior swordsman - merely that Anakin was now less outclassesd

Comment: @And, what's your basis for that? It's also possible that Anakin's improvements made him superior swordman. (P.S. See my first comment. I am not saying Anakin superior. I am saying nobody knows.) He may be inferior, equal or superior with equal chance unless you have a clear quote from the canon.

Answer (score 11):

It was not luck, or technique. It was rage-fueled Force (Dark side of it). Matthew Stover's ROTJ novelization expands on that:

> A starburst of clarity blossoms within Anakin Skywalker’s mind, when he says to himself Oh. I get it, now and discovers that the fear within his heart can be a weapon, too. ...
>   Dooku is dead already. The rest is mere detail.  ...
>   And all for nothing, because a nuclear flame has consumed Anakin Skywalker’s Jedi restraint, and fear becomes fury without effort, and fury is a blade that makes his lightsaber into a toy. ...
>   Dooku’s decades of combat experience are irrelevant. His mastery of swordplay is useless. ...Even his knowledge of the Force has become a joke. ...
>
> But Palpatine’s words *rage is your weapon* have given Anakin permission to unseal the shielding around his furnace heart, and all his fears and all his doubts shrivel in its flame.

And then, to the taking of the hands:

> In that pristine clarity, there is only one thing he must do.
>   Decide.
>   So he does.
>   He decides to win.
>   He decides that Dooku should lose the same hand he took. Decision is reality, here: his blade moves simultaneously with his will and blue fire vaporizes black Corellian nanosilk and disintegrates flesh and shears bone, and away falls a Sith Lord’s lightsaber hand, trailing smoke that tastes of charred meat and burned hair. The hand falls with a bar of scarlet blaze still extending from its spastic death grip, and Anakin’s heart sings for the fall of that red blade.
>   He reaches out and the Force catches it for him.
>   And then Anakin takes Dooku’s other hand as well.

Comment: **"that tastes of charred meat"** WTF?

Comment: ROTJ?? I think you mean ROTS...